# How could a true steampunk era have started?

Tags: science-fiction, alternate-history, steampunk

In the 17/1800s, England was very much powered by steam. However, not much advanced in the department outside of factory machinery. I feel that, had workers been given decent wages and hours, maybe inventors would have felt more inclined towards creating steam-powered devices for everyday people. But in this scenario, would coal- and electric-powered devices have been created more rapidly, due to the influx of people with time to do research of their own/with enough income to receive college educations?

What do you think would be the ideal scenario for a steampunk society to come about? Do you think there's a time in human history where we could have done a few things slightly differently and ended up with this instead?

Comment: I don't think it was a lack of desire or money - plenty of inventors tried to use steam to build engines (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steam_aircraft).  Rather, it was the rise of electricity and improvements in the refinement of petroleum.

Comment: "What do you think" is the cue to start close-vote for *too opinion-based*

Comment: @Tim That's really interesting, thanks for the page!

Comment: @Vylix But I'm hoping for a discussion. I'd much rather learn people's opinions on a no-right-answer matter than to just ask a black-and-white question.

Comment: @MollyTaylor a discussion for this topic is certainly will be fascinating! However, a discussion does not fit StackExchange Q&A format. A question should not invite people to discuss, but to answer. If you wish to discuss this, you are always welcome in our [chat]!

Comment: The answer to this question lies in railroad. Read about Isambard Brunel and why his  track gauge lost. Same thinking lead to slowing (or even stopping) development of steam which was soon surpassed by electricity.

Comment: The answer to this question lies in what makes steampunk viable. Even with our modern knowledge and tools, we can't really make steam engines that are as good as combustion or electric ones. So steampunk age will begin with discovery of unobtanium that makes steam power better than combustion and electricity.

Comment: Thanks, all! And thanks, Vylix, for helping me get used to this site! :)